# Максимальное кол-во Геттеров и Сеттеров

Tags: javascript

Искал информацию в оф. документациях, но так ничего и не нашел.

Какое максимально количество Getter и Setter может быть в одном объекте?

Правильно ли вообще в одном объекте устанавливать больше одного Getter и Setter?

Пример кода:

```
let obj = {};

Object.defineProperties(obj,{

getterAndSetter:{
set(setName){
//Какой-то код      
},

set(setAge){
//Какой-то код  
},

get(){
//Какой-то код      
},

get(){
//Какой-то код      
}   
},
})
```

Comment: явного ограничения на количество полей и методов - нет

Comment: Но у вас написан бред. В объекте не может быть одноимённых свойств по определению

Comment: Но Grundy сказал, что ограничения на свойства нет, то есть их можно писать сколько душе угодно. Я пытался дать имена get и set в Object.defineProperties но там выходила ошибка, пришлось обойтись без имён функций.

Comment: А как написать правильно? Скажите пожалуйста =)

Comment: А что вы хотите-то?

Comment: _Но Grundy сказал, что ограничения на свойства нет, то есть их можно писать сколько душе угодно._ - и ты их написал. Просто ты путаешь свойства которые объявляются в литерале объекта, с объектом настроек, который передается в `Object.defineProperties`, в котором каждому ключу соответствует конкретная настройка свойства либо поля.

Comment: Вы запутали меня. Alexey Ten говорит, что так делать нельзя это бесмысслено, так как сработает лишь один геттер и один сеттер а остальные не будут работать. А вы говорите, что можно писать несколько сеттеров и геттеров. Зачем вы путаете новичков)?

Comment: Пишите коротко и сыро. В итоге  непонятно, что вы хотели сказать.

Answer (score 2):

У вас написана какая-то глупость. В объекте по определению не может быть повторяющихся ключей, так что ваша запись:

```js
{
set(setName){
//Какой-то код      
},

set(setAge){
//Какой-то код  
},

get(){
//Какой-то код      
},

get(){
//Какой-то код      
}   
}
```

эквивалентна

```
{
/*
set(setName){
//Какой-то код      
},
*/
set(setAge){
//Какой-то код  
},
/*
get(){
//Какой-то код      
},
*/
get(){
//Какой-то код      
}   
}
```

т.е. из одноимённых свойств игнорируются все кроме последнего.

Именно поэтому непонятно чего же вы хотите добиться этим кодом.

Comment: Значит в одном свойстве в Object.defineProperties можно установить только один геттер и один сеттер? Остальные геттеры и сеттере в свойстве не будут работать?  И почему в  Object.defineProperties нельзя давать имена геттерам и сеттерам?

Comment: Очевидно да, у **одного** свойства может быть только **один** геттер и один сеттер. А зачем вам больше и как вы себе это вообще представляете?

Comment: И почему в Object.defineProperties нельзя давать имена геттерам и сеттерам?

Comment: Я прямо теряюсь. Вы определяете геттер для **свойства**. Вы можете определить сто свойств и у каждого определить свой геттер. Что вы понимаете под именем геттера  для меня загадка.

Comment: В любом свойстве в Object.defineProperties при попытке дать имена get и set выходит ошибка. Почему?

Comment: Потому что defineProperties ожидает что геттер описан в свойстве get. А как он иначе должен угадывать где у вас геттер?

Comment: Ну куда скинуть пример кода, чтобы вы все поняли =(

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
    get name(){ /* */ }
}
```

Используйте ключевые слова `get` или`set` перед именем свойства

---

В случае `Object.defineProperties` Вы немного запутались:
То что Вы вводили похоже на синтаксис к функции `defineProperty`, возможно, искали в нескольких источниках.

Правильное написание будет таким:

```js
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  "getAge": {
      get: () => {/**/}
   },
   "setAge": {
      ...
    },
   ...
})
```

или для `defineProperty`

```js
Object.property(obj, "getAge",  { get: () => {/**/} });
```

**Пояснение:** во всех трёх случаях мы указываем имя свойства

Comment: Так это тоже самое, что и у меня, только вы сделали перевели функцию в стрелочную. И почему Геттерам и Сеттарам нельзя давать имена в Object.defineProperties? И можно ли писать несколько сеттеров и геттеров в Object.defineProperties?

Answer (score 1):

Много. Похоже, пока память не кончится.

```js
~async function() {
  for (var obj=Object.create(null), n=0; ; ++n) {
    try {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, n, {
        get() { return 0 },
        set(x) {},
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Added " + n + " props", err)
    }

    if (n % 1000000 === 0) {
      console.log(`Keys: ${n}\nMemory: ${performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize}`)
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
    }
  }
}()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Я не понял, что значит "Много. Похоже, пока память не кончится"?
Alexey Ten сказал, что больше одного get и сет устанавливать смысла нет, остальные геттеры и сеттера не сработают в Object.defineProperties. И почему в Object.defineProperties нельзя давать имена get и set?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский, тебе не кажется, что мой код отличается от твоего?

Answer (score 0):

Явного ограничения на количество свойств (полей, методов) в объекте нет.

---

[`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) позволяет определить сразу несколько свойств у объекта. Для этого, вторым параметром в данный метод передается объект настроек, имеющий следующую структуру:

```
{
    [propertyName]: propertyDescriptor
}
```

То есть, каждый ключ объекта отвечает за имя нового свойства, значение, соответствующее этому ключу определяет тип и настройки нового свойства.

Свойства в объекте могут быть двух типов:

1. Свойства, которые непосредственно хранят какие-то данные. Данному типу соответствует следующая структура `propertyDescriptor`

   ```
   {
       value: ... // определяет значение свойства
       writable: boolean // определяет, можно ли изменить значение свойства с помощью оператора присваивания
       // общие настройки 
       enumerable: boolean // определяет перечислимое ли свойство
       configurable: boolean // определяет, можно ли удалить свойство либо изменить его тип
   }
   ```
2. Свойства, которые могут предоставлять доступ к каким-то данным. Данному типу соответствует следующая структура `propertyDescriptor`

   ```
   {
       get: function(){...} // определяет getter
       set: function(value){...}// определяет setter
       // общие настройки 
       enumerable: boolean // определяет перечислимое ли свойство
       configurable: boolean // определяет, можно ли удалить свойство либо изменить его тип
   }
   ```

---

В коде в вопросе идет попытка передать некорректный `propertyDescriptor` для свойства `getterAndSetter` вместо этого необходимо было сделать два отдельных свойства для `name` и `age`

```js
let obj = {};

Object.defineProperties(obj, {

  name: {
    set(value) {
      console.log('set name:', value);
    },
    get() {
      console.log('get name');
    },
  },
  age: {
    set(value) {
      console.log('set age:', value);
    },
    get() {
      console.log('get age');
    }
  }
});

obj.name = "new name";
obj.name;
obj.age = "new age";
obj.age;
```

В примере выше видно, что для обоих свойств вызываются и геттеры и сеттеры.

Так как эти свойства не хранят данные, чтобы значения запоминались нужно либо добавить соответствующие свойства, либо сохранять/получать значения из каких либо других переменных:

```js
var globalAge = 10;
let obj = {};

Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  $name: {
    value: 'Name',
    writable: true
  },
  name: {
    set(value) {
      console.log('set name:', value);
      this.$name = value;
    },
    get() {
      console.log('get name');
      return this.$name;
    },
  },
  age: {
    set(value) {
      console.log('set age:', value);
      globalAge = value;
    },
    get() {
      console.log('get age');
      return globalAge;
    }
  }
});

console.log('obj.name:', obj.name);
obj.name = "new name";
console.log('obj.name:', obj.name);

console.log('obj.age:', obj.age);
obj.age = "new age";
console.log('obj.age:', obj.age);
```